# PHP download from outside htdocs

Tags: php, html, download, directory

I am doing a testing on download and putting into zip file, I have no problems downloading it when it is inside a single file in webroot/htdocs for example images/, but I can't download it outside htdocs nor images/New_Folder. This code for form is for now working fine,

```
    <form name="zips" method="post" action='downloadFile.php'>

        <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="makeZipinPHP.jpg" />
        <img src="images/makeZipinPHP.jpg" /><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="tick.jpg" />
        <img src="images/tick.jpg" />

        <input type="submit" name="createpdf" value="Download as ZIP" />&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" name="reset"  value="Reset" />

    </form>
```

but can I change the src to example

```
   C:/images/New_Folder/tick.jpg
```

And this is for downloadFile.php which is also working as of now, but I want to change the

```
 $file_folder = "images/"
```

to for example $file_folder="C:/image/New_Folder/"
Is it possible?

```
    <?php
    $error = ""; //error holder
    if(isset($_POST['createpdf']))
    {
        $post = $_POST;
        $file_folder = "images/";// folder to load files
        if(extension_loaded('zip'))
        {
            // Checking ZIP extension is available
            if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0)
            {
                // Checking files are selected
                $zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library
                $zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
                if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
                {
                    // Opening zip file to load files
                    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
                }
                foreach($post['files'] as $file)
                {
                    $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file); // Adding files into zip
                }
                $zip->close();
                if(file_exists($zip_name))
                {
                    // push to download the zip
                    header('Content-type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
                    readfile($zip_name);
                    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
                    unlink($zip_name);
                }

            }
            else
                $error .= "* Please select file to zip ";
        }
        else
           $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Server you have created ( localhost ) has its root at "htdocs" and it does not have access to any files of your computer....

So if you want to download / Render anyhting from the Server (Apache or any other) you have to place it in htDocs folder ..

Comment: even if the file is at htdocs/image/New_folder it cannot be accessed? Only htdocs/image?

Comment: No it can be accessed.... As long as it's inside the HTDOCS folder it's completely accessible

Comment: and you don't have to mention htdocs in the filepath

Just use  "/images/New_Folder"

Comment: I still can't access inside /images/New_Folder

Comment: which server are you using ?

Comment: server? I'm sorry I'm newbie at this. I think it's localhost??

Comment: There's no error, it runs a blank page if I change it to images/New/ or C:/images/New/

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$file_folder` to a full system folder path should work fine as long as it is expressed properly for your server environment (`c:\\image\\New_Folder\\` or `c:/image/New_Folder/` on Microsoft Windows) and there are no permissions issues or restrictions enforced on PHP (e.g. `open_basedir` etc).